# Receive a String from a Python Socket Server to a Java Socket Client

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, serversocket

I am making an Android App(using Background Services) that recives Strings from a Python Server the problem is that the Android Service receives the String only when the communication is interrupted.

**Java Code**

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable {

    private Client client;
    private Socket socket;
    private Thread receiver;
    private BufferedReader br;

    public Receiver(Socket socket, Client client) {
        this.socket =socket;
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        receiver = Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while(!receiver.isInterrupted()){
                String command = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Command Received: "+command);
                client.parseCommand(command);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            receiver.interrupt();
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            new Thread(new ConnectionController()).start();
        }

    }
}
```

I have also tried using DataInputStream but if i use it the String is never received by the Android Service.

**Python Code**

```
def send_command(self,command):
        self.currentClient[1].send(command.encode())
```

I use this method to send the Command String.

Comment: You're using `BufferedReader.readLine()`.  Does the command sent from python include an end-of-line character?

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i tought the send method of python sockets took care of that by default.